# Change the method to allow pass different values as parameters for the same variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method like below and it's working I have a $fields variable that then I need to merge it to another array.

```
public function definition(): array
    {

           $fields  = 
            NovaDependencyContainer::make([

                $this->listDefinition(
                    ‘Field’,
                    $this->getFields(),
                    2 // here can be 2 or 4
                )])
            ->dependsOn(‘is’_active, 0)
            ->meta()['fields'][0];

           return array_merge(
            [
                …
            ],
            $fields
        );
    }
```

However I want to have some way of having 2 variables `$fields`. Basically have something like below, which of course as it is doesn't work:

```
public function definition(): array
        {
    
               $fields  = 
                NovaDependencyContainer::make([
    
                    $this->listDefinition(
                        ‘Field’,
                        $this->getFields(),
                        2 // here can be 2 or 4
                    )])
                ->dependsOn(‘is’_active, 0)
                ->meta()['fields'][0];


               $fields  = 
                NovaDependencyContainer::make([
    
                    $this->listDefinition(
                        ‘Field’,
                        $this->getFields(),
                        4
                    )])
                ->dependsOn(‘is’_active, 1)
                ->meta()['fields'][0];

               return array_merge(
                [
                    …
                ],
                $fields
            );
        }
```

The only difference is the 2 or 4, that's the number of times the field will appear. And the other difference is the "dependsOn(‘is’_active, 1)" it can be 1 or 0 "`dependsOn('is_checked', 0)`".

I'm using a package "Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer" and basically if the checkbox "Is Checked" is selected I want to have "4", because with "4" it will show the fields 4 times otherwise I want to have 2.

Do you know how to properly change the method to allow for that?

Comment: you can add simple if check and send 1 parameter for 2 or 4 to the method.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem that simple because it depends on the result of " NovaDependencyContainer::make([
    
                    $this->listDefinition(
                        ‘Field’,
                        $this->getFields(),
                        4
           )])
                ->dependsOn(‘is’_active, 1)
                ->meta()['fields'][0]; or $this->listDefinition(
                        ‘Field’,
                        $this->getFields(),
                        4 )]) ->dependsOn(‘is’_active, 0)
                ->meta()['fields'][0];  ". Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    function definition(int $fieldCount): array
    {
        
        $fields  = NovaDependencyContainer::make([$this->listDefinition('Field', $this->getFields(), $fieldCount)])
                ->dependsOn('is_active', ($fieldCount == 4 ? 1 : 0))
                ->meta()['fields'][0];
    
        return array_merge(
            [
                …
            ],
            $fields
        );
    }
```

Comment: Then you should first run other function to check it and give it to this function or you can simply send users input for user check as boolean parameter

Comment: Thanks, but the $fieldCount is not known at the beginning of the function, it will be 2 or 4 only after the user checks or doesn't check the checkbox. When the user checks the checkbox the package uses Vue under the hood for this to work.

Comment: can you share vue component for it? You can also pass parameter inside vue. It is probably using axios and formData or simple json object

Comment: I dont know Vue, so I'm not exactly sure where that is happening, so I was trying to do on the PHP side.

Comment: can you check your request? Maybe vue is sending the checkbox status? If you can inspect vue component it would be easier

Comment: In the request there is not data about the checkbox status. For example        dd(request()->all()); shows "array:5 [
  "editing" => "true"
  "editMode" => "update"
  "viaResource" => "posts"
  "viaResourceId" => "1"
]".

Comment: So how will you detect the status checkbox's value? if it is not sending in request?

Comment: This "$fields  = NovaDependencyContainer::make([$this->listDefinition('Field', $this->getFields(), $fieldCount)])
                ->dependsOn('is_active', ($fieldCount == 4 ? 1 : 0))
                ->meta()['fields'][0];" will show the fields on the screen.  And it should 2 or 4 times according to if the checkbox was checked or not. But only when the update button of the form is clicked the form is submitted and there the status of checkbox is possible to get. However, I need to handle that previously of the form submission so it appear 2 or 4 times the fields for the user to fill.